# alloc init does not load component in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

i am using `UINavigationController` but when i push a view controller just simply by making object of the class the class load but not the components in it.
this is my `AppDelegate.m`

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
nav.viewControllers = @[vc];
```

and my first `UIViewController` if action button code is

```
NextView *next = [[NextView alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES ];
```

it gets to next `UIViewController` but no internal components are loaded such as - button,textfield,etc.

and if i try this code it give me runtime error

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NextView *next = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES ];
```

Comment: Have you given identifier in storyboard?

Comment: What kind of runtime error do you get? Paste log in the question, please.

Comment: which runtime error you get?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `NextView` inherit `UIViewController` and you have given identifier as `two` to that view controller and you have set class `NextView` from identity inspector to that viewcontroller.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could not get outlets (buttons etc.) to be loaded with `alloc` `init` in the subclass of UIViewController. You should init it with the xib file, using `-initWithNibName:bundle:` method. Or you can instantiate it with storyboard.

```
// You can get current storyboard from the View Controller 
UIStoryboard *sb = vc.storyboard;
NextView *next = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
```

Comment: @sahib, please tell us what error this method gives?